# Fos User command throws unexpected error in console

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, fosuserbundle, symfony-3.4

I am trying to create new user for user table in my local Symfony project.

I am using: `php bin/console fos:user:create my-user my@mail.com 12345`

When I am triggering command it throws:

> The parameter "" must be defined.

This was unexpected because I don't have any parameter defined with taht name.

When I try to add user manually it works.
`

Comment: Did you try to run command `php bin/console fos:user:create` without argument ? Fos will ask you for username/mail and password

Comment: It goes well until I type password. After I hit 'enter' it throws an error again. @Alexis

Comment: Maybe a special character in your password that FOS don't like ? You can try with a really basic password like `test` ?

Comment: No it's a basic password that I tried in different projects. The parameter name is the second project src folder name. As I have "src/AppOne" na "src/AppTwo" it throws The parameter "apptwo" must be defined. Maybe something with that? @Alexis

Comment: But on the other side docker runs and everything works, so I can't figure out where the issue is. @Alexis

Comment: Could you explain more that in your main post for everyone please

Comment: I solved it! I was some parameter that was lefted in dist file but not i parameters.yml file. Thank you for tying. @Alexis

Comment: Great :) no problem